# How to share access to application insights data in the azure portal with other azure users

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, azure-resource-manager

We have added Application Insights to our app, but I'm unable to make the application insights data availible to other developers (azure users). This is what I've tried:

- Added a new Resource Group
- Added a new Application Resource to it
- Added a colleague that has another azure subscription, added as role Contributor to the resource group
- Verified that the user is listed as inherited access in the application insight resource

Application insights data is showing up fine in my portal, problem is that my colluages are not able to locate the resource or the resource group in her azure portal. I've tried by sending a link, but the azure portal just says "loading"

Question is: Do I need to give some other access to allow for sharing application insights?

Thanks for any help

Larsi

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you mention "developer" I'm assuming you are both using separate MSDN subscriptions, and thats whats causing the issue.  If this is the scenario that you are each using your own MSDN subscriptions when you log in, the other developer need to "switch" to your "directory" after they sign in, in order to see the things you gave them access to.  Once the other dev is logged in to the azure portal, have them click their name in the upper right of the browser window, and in that dropdown there will likely be an additional "directory" that they can select which effectively switches them to see things that are inside your subscription+directory.  Its this extra level of the "Directory" that is probably hiding your AI resource from him.
I experienced this problem first hand in the exact scenario you have described.

Comment: I would like to add here is that you will not see this "switch" unless you yourself have a personal Visual Studio account. With the same email address, you need to create a personal Visual Studio Online account - getting your own subdomain xxx.visualstudio.com

Answer (score 4):

There is a lot of information about setting up access control for Application Insights here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-insights-resources-roles-access-control/

It looks like you've done most of those things, but you might want to double check just in case.  Also, you shouldn't need to assign them "contributor", which would allow them to edit things, you should only need to give them "reader" access so they can see the data.